# Matrix Rows Data Put Into Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS report for matrix output. I want matrix rows (month name) data into variables/parameter and then perform a certain select statement on these values. Remember month is being changed and parameter/variable value also changed accordingly.

[image: Report Output]

Comment: Clarify what you have and the matrix you expect

Comment: You need to create a dataset similar to what you use for your report but only retrieve DISTINCT month/years. Then use that dataset as the Values (Values from query) for your parameter. Then do what you want with the param.

Comment: as u see in picture...wants to run single sql query which value will be changed as per the month value

Comment: Issue resolve through lookup function. Through lookup function you can get other dataset value. Hopes it will support you. Cheers !!!